# Use a specified method with Oj.dump instead of as_json or to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to specify a method to use for serialization when using Oj.dump rather than having it just default to to_json or as_json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Oj` doesn't have the option to set a default method to call, but it'll happily serialize the result of calling that method yourself.

```
Oj.dump(data.special_as_json)
```

This is also a good place for a presenter object that implements the method you want as `to_json`.

```
class Glove
  private attr_reader :obj

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def as_json(opts = {})
    {
      # ...
    }
  end
end

Oj.dump(Glove.new(data))
```

Since it seems like you're trying to avoid typing anything beyond `Oj.dump`, you can write a wrapper around `Oj` that does the work.

```
module Ok
  def self.dump(obj)
    Oj.dump(obj.special_as_json)
  end
end

Ok.dump(data)
```

And of course, monkeypatching `Oj` is always an option, but not a good one.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid doing anything beyond Oj.dump.  My use case is such that within the same Model I have to return different json data payloads.  With the Oj behavior of looking for as_json/to_json to serialize and the recommended approach of overriding these it didn't appear to allow for this.  Essentially I want to be able to do something like `Oj.dump(obj, meth_name)` and then meth_name would be used for serialization rather than to_json.

I'm a little unclear what happens if I use your first suggestion of `Oj.dump(data.special_as_json)`.  Wouldn't Oj still call to_json at this point?

Comment: Check out the [`:mode` option](https://github.com/ohler55/oj#options) for details on this, but Oj doesn't need to call `*_json` on the Hash that `special_as_json` would return - it just drops to C and serializes it. Oj only looks for a `to/as_json` method if you set `mode: :compat` and dump an object it can't handle natively, otherwise the default mode (`:object`) just dumps all the instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try out

```rb
Oj.generate({a: 'test'})
```

```rb
my_hash = {a: 'test'}
Oj.dump(my_hash, mode: :compat)
```